# Structures and Arrays (too many initializers for ‘Array’ ) C++

Tags: c++, arrays, c++11, structure

Why I get error :too many initializers for ‘Array’ 
Its C++11 code and I dont know where is problem

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

struct Point {
int x,y ;
};
Point points[3] {{1,2},{3,4},{5,6}};
int x2 = points[2].x;

struct Array {
Point elem[3];
};

int main() {
    cout << "!!!\nStructure!!!" << endl; //

    Array points2  {{1,2},{3,4},{5,6}};// *too many initializers for‘Array’* 
    int y2 = points2.elem[2].y;

    cout << "!!!here points2 = !!!" << y2 <<endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Array points2  {{{1,2},{3,4},{5,6}}};    SOLVED

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You actually need one more set of braces to initialize that `struct`

```
Array points2  {{{1,2},{3,4},{5,6}}};
//               ^Point
//              ^Point[]
//             ^Array
```

[Working example](http://ideone.com/al03Nb)